# How to get the value in table while knowing other value in the same entry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, search

I have a `membership` table, which includes

```
MemberID(int), 
Username(varchar16), 
Password... etc.
```

How would I get the MemberID if I know only the username? I'm using SQL ASP.Net C#.

Comment: If you are using the membership infrastructure, why are you not using it for this? You can retrieve a user by username only.

Comment: See [`GetUser(string, bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwzxkby7.aspx) on `MembershipProvider`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the value of the `username`. Use it as the condition in your where clause. I assumed here that `username` is unique or else you will have all IDs of the members that matches to the specified username.

```
SELECT MemberID
FROM Membership
WHERE Username = 'usernameHere'
```

try this, since you are using ADO.Net

```
// other codes heres 
string MemberID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
// the MemberID variable already holds the value of the ID
// that matches your username.
```

Comment: I got that far, I think I was confused on how I would store it into an int variable. This is on a webpage(aspx.cs), I had new SqlCommand("SELECT MemberID...") how would I use the MemberID on my page?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MemberId FROM Member WHERE UserName = 'username'
```

Say the UserName is not a unique column it would return multiple rows that match the username
so you are better of adding a TOP(1) in your query.
Else you can do a SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(), this will return the first MemberId that matches the username

```
SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```